# Fermionic condensation

Tags: superconductivity

In the case of bosonic condensation such as BEC all the boson particles condensate into ground state. But fermion follow pauli exclusion principle so what is meant by fermionic condensation in superconductivity?

Comment: In superconductivity, electrons usually pairwise form a type of bound-state called a cooper pair. These cooper pairs are bosons and condense. It's not the fermions that directly condense, it's certain bosons made out of fermions.